# How to write a callback for Zapier

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, zapier

I have a nodejs function in Lambda that works fine. However when I try to integrate it with Zapier. The function doesn’t return a value to Zapier. Is their a specific way to callback your function in lambda so that Zapier can receive the returned values?

Comment: You shouldn't need anything specific. Have you read through https://zapier.com/help/aws-lambda? If so, could you provide a simplified version of your function here so we can see and test?

Comment: @xavdid the function works fine my callback looks like this `callback(null, {"statusCode": 200, "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, "body": labels });` where labels is a string. As I said function works fine, labels has content within it hwoever nothing is returned to Zapier

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can show as some code to get an idea. My guess is that you return an object to Zapier, while Zapier always expects an array of data. If I am correct, try to wrap your object in array before send.